# Android repository unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

I have an issue with my repository unit testing where I don't get the expected result. Can anyone point me out my problem please.

In the tests, reading out from the repository gives me an unexpected value.

Here is my repository code -

```
interface DataRepository {
   suspend fun changeCustomDataBasedOnAction(action: MyAction): Result
}

class DataRepositoryImpl(
    private val cacheRepository: CacheRepository
) : DataRepository {

    override suspend fun changeCustomDataBasedOnAction(action: MyAction): Result {
        when (action) {
            is MyAction.StoreUser -> {
                print("Storing to cache" + action.userName + action.userAge)
                cacheRepository.storeUserDetails(
                    UserModel(
                        action.userName,
                        action.userAge
                    )
                )
                return isUserDetailsStored()
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun isUserDetailsStored(): Result {
        val result = cacheRepository.retrieveUserDetails()
        print("Reading from cache" + result)
        if (result is Result.GetUserDetails) {
            return Result.UserDetailsStored
        }
        return Result.UserDetailsNotStored
    }
}
```

This is my corresponding unit test -

```
class DataRepositoryImplTest {

    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var dataRepository: DataRepository

    @Mock
    private lateinit var cacheRepository: CacheRepository

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        dataRepository = DataRepositoryImpl(cacheRepository)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    fun data_storeUser_returnUserDetailsStored() {
        runBlocking {

            `when`(
                dataRepository.changeCustomDataBasedOnAction(
                    MyAction.StoreUser(
                        "username", "40"
                    )
                )
            ).thenReturn(Result.UserDetailsStored)

            val result = dataRepository.changeCustomDataBasedOnAction(
                    MyAction.StoreUser(
                        "username", "40"
                    )
            )

            Assert.assertEquals(result, Result.UserDetailsStored)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I get this test result -

```
Storing to cache username40

Reading from cache null

Storing to cache username40

Reading from cache com.user.app.Result$UserDetailsStored@2584b82d

java.lang.AssertionError: 

Expected :com.user.app.Result$UserDetailsNotStored@7bbc8656

Actual   :com.user.app.Result$UserDetailsStored@2584b82d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you doing UnitTest incorrectly. This is not the responsibility of your UT class DataRepositoryImpl to check if the user has been stored successfully. if so, you need to provide the real instance of the cacheRepository.
Second, you can write two Unit test cases positive and negative like below

```
@Test
fun data_storeUser_returnUserDetailsStored() {
    runBlocking {

        `when`(cacheRepository.retrieveUserDetails())
        ).thenReturn(Result.GetUserDetails)

        val result = dataRepository.changeCustomDataBasedOnAction(
            MyAction.StoreUser(
                "username", "40"
            )
        )

        Assert.assertEquals(result, ListenableWorker.Result.UserDetailsStored)
    }
}

@Test
fun data_storeUser_returnUserDetailsNotStored() {
    runBlocking {

        `when`(cacheRepository.retrieveUserDetails())
        ).thenReturn(Result.UserDetailsNotStored)

        val result = dataRepository.changeCustomDataBasedOnAction(
            MyAction.StoreUser(
                "username", "40"
            )
        )

        Assert.assertEquals(result, ListenableWorker.Result.UserDetailsNotStored)
    }
}
```

Unit test case for checking actual caching of data can be written separately in the cacheRepository test class.

Comment: Thanks. But still the test 'data_storeUser_returnUserDetailsStored' fails with 'result' being always 'Result.UserDetailsNotStored'. Is it the reason that my 'DataRepositoryImpl' is a singleton?

Comment: @Maria Yes you have to debug why the condition (result is Result.GetUserDetails ) is still failing even though we have mocking the behaviour  `when`(cacheRepository.retrieveUserDetails())
        ).thenReturn(Result.GetUserDetails)

Possibility is that the instances are different hence the condition fails

Comment: It works now... some silly mistake of mine. thanks a ton :)

Comment: @Maria Glad to hear.